# Gitlab suffers fatal error after running PHP Unit but tests pass

Tags: laravel, gitlab, phpunit

> Fatal error: Uncaught `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException`: Target [`Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler`] is not instantiable. in `/builds/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php` on line 1017
>
> `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException`: Target [`Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler`] is not instantiable. in `/builds/xxx/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php` on line 1017

This error occurs after Gitlab passes the test which causes the pipeline to fail which isn't nice.

All the tests pass locally and the error does not occur there - only within GitLab.

I can just force the merge but then it will mean the pipeline will always fail which is a bit silly and pointless.

This is within an upgrade to Laravel 8.

I reran the pipeline in case it was a gremlin.  Might try again.

The last point it gets to before calling exceptions is:

> `Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()`

What would be bet the best way forward?  Especially as this is within the vendor folder so unchangable.

Thanks!!!

---

Edit: The issue is something to do with the coverage report which I can live without for now but would like to turn back on.  But if I remove the --coverage-text flag it passes.  This feels a bit hacky and ignoring the problem but it's okay for now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried composer dump-autoload. That should solve the issue

Comment: I'm under the impression that Gitlab is fetching new versions each time but if there's a way I can tell it to do that I will try and see if it resolves.

Comment: I put the command to dump-autoload in before running the test and this unfortunately had no effect.

Comment: Upon further investigation it seems that this is a triggered with the coverage report.  When I turn that off it works.

Comment: try adding this `php artisan config:cache` after artisan migrate and see if it helps

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` is already part of the pipeline but I tried moving it to after the migration but unfortunately no change.  Thanks though :)